# bluescreen Page_Fault_in_non_paged_area after windows login

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, bluescreenview

One PC in our office suddenly got bluescreens when trying to log into windows user, after entering password when windows was loadinng.
The Bluescreen error message was

> Page_Fault_in_non_paged_area

I took out each of the rams and tested with only one of them. got the same error with both of them.
I googled a bit and found that there might be a problem with windows update and remembered that last week my college was confused and asked for help why there is a message to restart her pc... we put the windows update queue at the end of the work day on friday. bluescreen since monday.
Now I just tried to reinstall windows and got the

> Windows cannot install required file. The file is maybe damaged or
>   missing. Make sure all files required for the installation are present and
>   restart the installation
>   Errorcode: 0x80070570

In windows installation which I tried from 2 different USB sticks which was prepared from windows 10 boot USB stick tutorial. The error occures when it is finished preparing the files for installation and switches to the third part "feature installation"
I am trying to install it at the main ssd drive 256 gb which I deleted and formated in the installation process. I also tried to not press on new after deleting all the partitions to let the installation try to create the partitions.

Do you know what else I can try?
Where might be the error? What Hardwarecomponent? drive or ram?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's RAM issue. Page_Fault_in_non_paged_area usually refers to the case when he required data was not found in the memory page.
Potentially it could also be faulty motherboard DRAM slots or chipset (RAM controller is in the CPU).

In rare cases can be also a SSD/HDD issue if system dll can't be read or read with issues to memory from the storage. This can also happen when system files are cached in the faulty pagefile.sys.

Comment: we did change the SSD to an HDD, now its working again. Haven´t had the time to check the ssd on another PC tho.

Comment: @veritaS yes, it sometimes can be also a drive if system dll  can't be read or read with issues to memory from the storage. This can also happen when dlls are cached in the pagefile.sys